# Counter() subtract

Tags: python, list, counter, subtraction

I have two list that i want to subtract frequency of elements in list pos from neg. So:

```
neg = [x for x in all[:800000]]
pos = [x for x in all[800000:]]
count_pos = Counter(pos)
count_neg = Counter(neg)
positivity = count_pos.subtract(count_neg)
print(positivity)
```

I expect to get results but the code return:

```
None
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Try: `print(count_pos)`.

Comment: The method "subtract" doesn't return anything, therefore you got None.

Comment: @SuperSaiyant, hat is ok. a Counter that show element: frequency pairs.

Comment: @kuonb, So what should to do?

Comment: As SuperSaiyan said, the solution is in "count_pos", so just print it to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments on the question point out, the `subtract` method is applied to its object in place and returns None. To get the behaviour you want you can either use the `-` operator like so:

```
positivity = count_pos - count_neg
```

or you can first make a copy of your `count_pos` Counter and use its subtract method:

```
positivity = Counter(count_pos)
positivity.subtract(count_neg)
```

In both cases you end up with a variable `positivity` that contains the difference between count_pos and count_neg

Comment: Thanks @bunji, but - does not work for negative output.

Comment: The first example, using the `-` operator will only give outputs of at least 1. But the second example I gave should return negative outputs. From the [Counter docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.subtract): "... Both inputs and outputs may be zero or negative."

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the corresponding line with

```
positivity = count_pos - count_neg
```